# Panels on frontpage

Tags: 6, panels

I'm trying to use Panels module on my drupal's frontpage.

I've created view called `front_page` with path set to *front*, proper node panel, set selection rules to URL (i've tried both *front* and `<front>`) but no matter what i'll set in Panel variant settings, i'm allways getting the default front page provided by drupal (or the one set in *Site Information*). When i'll change my variant's URL to i.e. *node/**, it works fine. I simply can't just set a selection rule for front page.

Do you have any idea what am i possibly doing wrong ?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in panels there is a option for set the panel as homepage.

that checkbox the only thing to do is set here: http://yoursite/admin/settings/site-information

the path of your panel as homepage.

So, if the url of your panel is "home-page"  then just in the site-information section put that path as a homepage.

Comment: hmm where is that 'make this panel homepage' checkbox exactly ? I was reading something about it earlier but wasn't able to find it

Comment: oh it's ok, i've found it, i forgot that there is an option to create `Page Panel` in `Panels` module. Thanks!